# How do I target a url like this with CSS or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a video page that has filters for the videos. If I click on one of the filters (e.g. "music videos"), the url changes to something like this:

`http://mysite.com/videos/?videofilter=music-videos`

Unfortunately, there isn't a body class added or anything where I can easily target it by doing something like this:

`body.music-videos {  }`

Is there a way to somehow target the url using CSS or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Javascript's `location.href` to get the location, and work with it like a normal string.
But it would be much more recommended to server-side the body to have a class.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your page loads with that URL - can't you do somehting when you render the page to include something css-detectable?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question. Are you trying to target a link with an href value? You should be able to target that with something like selector[src=URL] in css.  If you're trying to target the body tag based on the URL I would create conditional scripts under if statements such as if(location.href=='url'){ document.getElementsByTagName("body").style.property="whatever" } . Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand...

So you click the filter options, which sends a query string to the URL. We can get the query string as such:

```
var qs = [];
var q = window.location.search.substring(1);
var p = q.split('&');
for(var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
  var pos = p[i].indexOf('=');
  if(pos > 0) {
    var key = p[i].substring(0, pos);
    var val = p[i].substring(pos+1);
    qs[key] = val;
  }
}
```

Then you simply access `qs['videofilter']`to get the value. From there, if it's doing nothing, well – you don't have a filter, you have check boxes. The only way to have a filter is to have some form of commonality by which to categorize them all. If you're wanting to do this through javascript and css, you could use that filter in a regex to find the specific tag whose `innerHTML` matches the value you got above, then determine the whole container's relationship( e.g. parent, grandparent, etc. ), and set that to `display:none;`

If you mean something else, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is Firefox only unfortunately:

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@-moz-document

```
       @-moz-document url(http://www.w3.org/),
                   url-prefix(http://www.w3.org/Style/),
                   domain(mozilla.org)
    {
      /* CSS rules here apply to:
         + The page "http://www.w3.org/".
         + Any page whose URL begins with "http://www.w3.org/Style/"
         + Any page whose URL's host is "mozilla.org" or ends with
           ".mozilla.org"
       */

      /* make the above-mentioned pages really ugly */
      body { color: purple; background: yellow; }
}
```